# Excel get_Range missing when interop assembly is embedded in .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, excel, interop, .net-4.0, com-interop

I build an assembly referencing a COM interop DLL.  If I embed the COM interop types by setting Embed Interop Types to True in the Reference's properties (VS2010), at run-time an error occurs "object does not contain a definition for get_Range".  If COM interop types are not embedded then no error occurs.

Does anyone know why a particular method, Worksheet.get_Range should be ommitted or how to work around this or have any other relevant insights?  I should be grateful for any help.

The interop dll contains a reference to Worksheet.get_Range(object, [object]).  Using reflector on my calling assembly there is no mention of get_Range under Worksheet.

The interop assembly I am embedding is generated from Excel9.olb.  I am not using PIAs as the application targets multiple Excel versions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have not tried this out myself yet, but I believe that the syntax has changed when using embedded COM Interop types under C# 4.0 to a more "C# friendly" syntax.

Therefore, instead of looking for the `get_Range(object, [object])` method, you can either omit the optional parameter (instead of having to provide `Type.Missing`), or you can avoid calling the get accessor completely, and instead reference the property name using square brackets:

```
// Using C# 3.0:
Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing);

// Using C# 4.0, omitting the optional parameter:
Excel.Range range = worksheet.get_Range("A1");

// Using C# 4.0, utilizing square-bracket indexing:
Excel.Range range = worksheet.Range["A1"];
```

From what I understand, though, you should still be able to call it the "old way", where the new indexer syntax is really calling the required 'get' and 'set' accessor behind the scenes, so I don't really know why you are having trouble. My guess is that you need to look under `Worksheet.Range` instead of `Worksheet.get_Range` within the IntelliSense listing. If this does not work for you, then it sounds like something may be wrong with your setup or installation.

For more on this, see: [Indexed Properties in C# 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/10/20/indexed-properties-in-c-4-0.aspx) by Kirill Osenkov.

Hope this helps...

Mike

Comment: MIke, thanks for your help.  The single parameter approach does not get a run-time error and is obviously a good workaround.  I have submitted a bug report to Microsoft 530769.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/530769/get-range-method-missing-with-embedded-interop-assembly?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Ah, right, I posted a bad link in my previous comment, thanks for correcting that. The discussion there is very interesting, and makes sense. But, may I ask, isn't the easiest solution to now simply use the `worksheet.Range["A1"]` syntax instead of the older `worksheet.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing)` now that you are using C# 4.0? You have found a very interesting curiosity, but as for fixing it for your own code, it would seem easiest and best to just use the new syntax -- which is easier to read in any case (by design!).

Comment: Mike, I agree that there was an obvious workaround as soon as I tested your suggested approach and I have long since adopted a variation.  The continuing discussion was strictly to help Microsoft's efforts to make the backward compatiblity as good as possible (and it is an impressive achievement).

On a point of detail I can't say that I prefer the "A1" approach or even "R1C1".  I don't particularly want to convert numbers into strings just to make the call (and for all I know Excel converts them straight back).  Perhaps its a matter of taate.  Thanks for your continuing interest.

Comment: Ok, no, I was not suggesting to actually make use of the string "A1" to designate the cell. I was simply saying that, using C# 4.0, one can, and should, make use of the worksheet.Range[object] syntax instead of the worksheet.get_Range(object, object) syntax. That's all. It's simpler, cleaner, and works as originally intended, using the property's name ("Range") instead of exposing the get accessor ("get_Range"). But I could see where this could be a huge problem if trying to migrate a lot of code from C# 3.0 to C# 4.0. A smart Regex replace could do it -- but make sure you have unit tests!

Answer (score 2):

This was raised as a bug with Microsoft at beta stage https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=530769&wa=wsignin1.0 and was resolved as By Design after RTM.  Mike Rosenblum's answer is approved there.

This can be summarised as Excel.Range r = sh.Range[sh.Cells[1, 1], sh.Cells[2, 2]]; where sh is a worksheet.